# How do I count the seconds from the start of the program in c?

Tags: c, time, while-loop

I want to make my program stop after a certain amount of time.
I have a while loop which runs forever, and I want it to stop after like, 60 seconds.

I've thought about using `<time.h>` with:

```
time_t start_time = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&start_time);
```

to get current time, and each iteration of the loop gets the current time again, and then substruct the seconds or minutes. but this won't work if for example the user runs the program at 23:59, and it changes to 00:00.

So how can I make my while loop break on a some kind of condition that says for example: X seconds have passed?

Comment: `while(time(NULL) - start_time < 60) Sleep(0);`. The value is seconds since epoch.

Comment: oh I can substruct them? it works like that?

Comment: You can *subtract* them.

Comment: yeah mb English isn't my strong side. thank you!

Comment: It's pretty good :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for heavy-weight functions and types, not to mention the problem you see when crossing certain points in wall time.

The most simple way is to use the old function `clock()`. It returns a "ticker" value with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` increments per second.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DELAY_S 10

int main(void) {
    puts("Started");
    clock_t start_clocks = clock();
    while (clock() - start_clocks < DELAY_S * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    puts("Stopped");
}
```